# Java using "-cp" and "-jar" together

Tags: java

Earlier, I had just one jar file and the manifest was set up such that I can simply run my program as:

```
 java -jar MyApp.jar
```

Now, I have separated my functionality into two jar files - MyCore.jar and MyApp.jar.

The following command works:

```
java -cp "*" com.mycompany.mypackage.App
```

But I cannot get the following to work

```
java -cp "*" -jar MyApp.jar
```

I get a ClassNotFoundException.

I prefer using "-jar" switch. Is there a way to make it work?

Comment: Does the jar file have a manifest file within it? I thought that the class-path information is supposed to be placed there.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels  You thought right.

Comment: @Andrew: I thought that what I thought was a correct thought. Thanks for corroborating it. 1+ to you.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels - I think you mean "Thanks for your thinks.  It was very thoughtful of you.".  HTH :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have a Manifest.mf file like this.

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Main-Class: com.mycompany.mypackage.App
Class-Path: MyApp.jar MyCore.jar log4j.jar
```

You can just add any jar files you need to the Class-Path line. Then as long as the jars are in the class path you can run the java -jar command without -cp.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Adding class path to the manifest did the trick.

Comment: Glad I could help. I know how frustrating that can be. I've spent hours on that myself.

Answer (score 12):

As per the Java cli [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/solaris/java.html#jar) you can not combine -cp and -jar in the same command

> -jar   Execute  a program encapsulated in a JAR archive.  The first argument is the name of a JAR file instead of a startup class name.  In order for this option to work, the manifest
>                 of the JAR file must contain a line of the form Main-Class:classname.  Here, classname identifies the class having the public static void main(String[] args) method that serves as  your  application's  starting point.  See the Jar tool reference page and the Jar trail of the Java Tutorial for information about working with Jar files and Jar-file mani-
>                 fests.
>   When you use this option, the JAR file is the source of all user classes, and other user class path settings are ignored. Note that JAR files that can be run with the "java -jar" option can have their execute permissions set so they can be run without using "java -jar". Refer to Java Archive (JAR)
>                 Files.

In order to resolve this you will need to ensure the manifest in your application jar references both the Class that contains the main file and the classpath.

Answer (score 5):

Assuming both jar files are in the same folder and `com.mycompany.mypackage.App` is the main application class, try this command:

```
java -cp MyCore.jar;MyApp.jar com.mycompany.mypackage.App
```

It should work for you.

In case you insist on use of `-jar` switch (*why?*), then you need to have your manifest file modified, to add `Class-Path` key and specify path to all related jar files. It makes your application less flexible in case jar files are not packaged with your main app jar file.

Comment: This is the best answer

Comment: Please note, the class path separator depends on the platform. For Windows it is `;`, but for Unix-like platform it is `:`. See the `path.separator` system property.

Comment: Actually, according to the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/solaris/java.html#jar), `-cp` should use `:` on any platform.

Answer (score 3):

Add a manifest that both specifies the class containing `main()` as well as the class-path.  See [Working with Manifest Files: Adding Classes to the JAR File's Classpath](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/downman.html) for more details.

Then the entire app. can be launched using `-jar`, without needing `-cp`.

Comment: This is no option, if you download a already singed JAR.