# Running JAVA Programs with additional -cp in ubuntu

Tags: java, ubuntu

I'm attempting to run CPUSIM under ubuntu 16.4

> java -cp .:richtextfx-fat-0.6.10.jar:reactfx-2.0-MR.jar 
>                  -jar CPUSim-4.0.11.jar

Is the line the readme file says to enter in, when i try using that line the program fails. I'm not that versed with java or runtime stuff under ubuntu. I'm trying to run it in a terminal that's in the file directory where i unzipped the file.

Any tips on using -cp with java in a terminal?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java using "-cp" and "-jar" together](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12047758/java-using-cp-and-jar-together)

Comment: something like this should work if you have your jars in a lib folder like we do.
java -cp "inbot.jar:lib/*" io.inbot.MainClass
should also work with -jar like you do. What error are you getting?

Comment: What exact failure do you get?  File not found?  No main class?

Comment: I don't think it's linking to the class files properly. So I'm getting class def not found