# Asterisk-Java can't find fastagi-mapping.properties

Tags: asterisk, asterisk-java

I'm using Asterisk and I'd like to emit a call from my Java app and then use an AGI script to control what happens. So I've got a first class that contacts the Asterisk server and uses an `OriginateAction` to start the call (this works well) and an AGI server that runs and should serve AGI requests. Though, it doesn't work because it can't find the `fastagi-mapping.properties` file.

Here is my `fastagi-mapping.properties`:

```
alertcall.agi = AlertCallScript
```

(It only has one case.)

In the same folder, I have `AlertCallScript.java` (and `asterisk-java.jar`) that I compile like this:

```
javac -cp asterisk-java.jar:. AlertCallScript.java ExamplesAsteriskSettings.java
```

And then I start my AGI server using this (found in the doc):

```
java -cp asterisk-java.jar:. -jar asterisk-java.jar
```

When I emit my call, I get the following error in the AGI server output:

```
Jun 13, 2018 6:28:12 AM org.asteriskjava.fastagi.ResourceBundleMappingStrategy loadResourceBundle
INFO: Resource bundle 'fastagi-mapping' not found.
Jun 13, 2018 6:28:12 AM org.asteriskjava.fastagi.internal.AgiConnectionHandler run
SEVERE: No script configured for URL 'agi://localhost/alertcall.agi' (script 'alertcall.agi')
```

And I don't know why... I've been looking into this for more than an hour and I probably made a stupid mistake, though I can't find it.

**Notes :**

- I use my classpath `java-asterisk.jar:.` to be able to have `asterisk-java` and the current folder, which contains the `fastagi-mapping.properties` file, so the file should be found without any problem within the class path.
- I have already try to delete and recreate the file, it didn't change anything.

Please suggest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Part of the problem is probably trying to use `-cp` and `-jar` in the same `java` command, this is not supported and there are a number of questions on Stackoverflow about that ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12047809/924) is one).

You can use something like

> java -cp asterisk-java.jar:. DefaultAgiServer

to start asterisk-java's `DefaultAgiServer` specifically (which is what specifying `-jar asterisk-java.jar` is going to do anyways, if I remember the entry in the manifest correctly).

Comment: Yep. That was it. Thanks a lot.